# how to create recycle view with card view once click card view it's open new fragment activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

how to create recycle view with card view once click card view it's open new fragment activity ?

I like to create the [android app for tutorials](http://www.techinfoworld.com/category/android/) I successfully create the list view with card view

I like to how to open new fragment while click on the list view with card view

The fragment will be showed in new activity with load my website url

Www.techinfoworld.com

how to done this please help me

Here I have attached the list view with card model [view link](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/11/android-recyclerview-example.html)

MainActivity.java

```
package androidwarriors.recycleviewdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        RecyclerAdapter adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
package androidwarriors.recycleviewdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RecyclerAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

    String [] name={"Androidwarriors","Stackoverflow","Developer Android","AndroidHive",
            "Slidenerd","TheNewBoston","Truiton","HmkCode","JavaTpoint","Javapeper"};
Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv1.setText(name[position]);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        holder.imageView.setTag(holder);
    }

    View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RecyclerViewHolder vholder = (RecyclerViewHolder) v.getTag();
            int position = vholder.getPosition();

            Toast.makeText(context,"This is position "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        }
    };



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.length;
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewHolder.java

```
package androidwarriors.recycleviewdemo;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv1,tv2;
    ImageView imageView;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tv1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        tv2= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_desc);
        imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_avatar);

    }
}
```

Comment: Put your recycler view item inside card view in layout XML, and inside your adapter code set view click listener for item.

Comment: i am a beginner to create android app, can you explain it briefly ??

Comment: Dear , if you are a beginner so first thing you should read some tutorial about how to set data in recycler view . Then you can customize your recycler row with card view. Hope it will help you.

Comment: please check the link i have added in the question section , i am using the same design for my app, i like to know once click on the any of the list it will be open the new fragment activity with my website page load ?

Comment: i successfully finished the layout and card view , but i dont know how to add code for click any of the list view item it will goes to the respective fragments activity , can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Adapter class add the following code for Recycler View item click:

```
@Override  
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) { 
         // holder.itemView is your RelativeLayout which is inside your cardview
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //do your further respective fragment activity task
            } 
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: how to seperate it for each list to click to load new fragment activity ??

Comment: In my recycleadapter.java file i am having the below code , where i change it , please help me.

Comment: public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv1.setText(name[position]);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        holder.imageView.setTag(holder);
    }
    View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RecyclerViewHolder vholder = (RecyclerViewHolder) v.getTag();
            int position = vholder.getPosition();
            Toast.makeText(context,"This is position "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

Comment: based on the position you will have to decide which activity should be displayed.
e.g. if position=0 then if wish to open Activity1 then your code should be as
switch(position )
{
case 0:
  Intent intent=new Intent(ReclyerActivityContext, Activity1.class);
ReclyerActivityContext.startActivity(intent);
break;
default: 
break;

}

Comment: :) don't forget to vote up if it solve your problem ;)

Comment: Ya sure :) , tomorow i will try it on my android studio if its work means i will surely voteup your answer , if any error occurs i will inform  you

Comment: I added the coded part full section on question section, can you remodified the code where i change it to achieve my solution, if you had time please provide the remodify code , @Rajendra

Comment: edit option is not enabled for me because another edit is in progress, I will try to do it later.

Comment: can you edit it now, i think now its work to edit it , thank you

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rajendra, Now i will try this code on app and tell you , how it works or not

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv1.setText(name[position]);
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    holder.imageView.setTag(holder);
}

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do your further respective fragment activity task
        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent intent=new Intent(your RecyclerActivity Reference, OneFragment.class);
                (Your Activity Reference).startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: In the above i am facing some error , holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() here holder will shows the error.............   next position will shows the error ...... next in recycleractivity reference and your activity refernce what name i like to include , please help me clarify the doubts